# ajax interface without then

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I want to package a ajax call into an interface without then.

If i do like this, it will just return 'No ajax return';

```
var ajaxReturn = ajaxFunction();
function ajaxFunction(){
    var text = 'No ajax return';
    // get fileName using an ajax get
    $.ajax();
    return text;
}
```

If i do like this, it will be ugly for using then;

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var text = 'No ajax';
    var dtd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax();
    return dtd.promise();
}

$.when(ajaxFunction()).then();
```

I just want the interface to be simple and return the right thing, can i?

```
//return the right
var ajaxReturn = ajaxFunction();
```

Comment: No. I think you just can't since ajax is asynchronous and you must have some mechanic to handle it **for ex** as you have deferred or `$.when` and `.then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var text = 'No ajax';
    var dtd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax();
    return dtd.promise();
}

$.when(ajaxFunction()).then();
```

Whoa, what is all that? You do need `.then` but you don't need most of the surrounding stuff. `$.ajax` *generates a promise for you*. You don't need to make a promise object yourself. In fact, often the only reason you need to manually set up a Deferred/Promise directly is if you're using some library that sets up callbacks and doesn't use promises itself.

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    return $.ajax();
}

ajaxFunction().then(function(data) { ... });
```

Now, let's say that you didn't actually want to return the JSON structure on the end of the ajax function; you want to take out just a number from inside of it, or tweak one value to make it an easier-to-use function for its callers. Easy enough:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    return $.ajax().then(function(data) {
      return data[12].number;
    }
}

ajaxFunction().then(function(number) { ... });
```

In direct answer to your question: No, what you asked for isn't possible. Whenever your JavaScript methods are running, the browser can't process other events like clicks and even basic scroll operations. So, any long-running operations (like contacting the server) do not return straight away, and instead offer a callback operation.

Answer (score 0):

Well..., *ajax* is asynchronous so you either use `.then()` or use a *callback* logic... Doing synchronous ajax is not a option for me, so I won't even mention it.

The alternative to `.then()` would be something like this:

```
ajaxFunction(function(res){ // pass a function into it
    // this will be called when the ajax is done
    alert(res);
});
function ajaxFunction(callback){
    // get fileName using an ajax get
    $.ajax({
        success: callback
    });
}
```

But again, maybe you can use just a normal ajax callback pattern anyway

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(res){
        // use the res
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous. `then` is designed to make writing async operations look more similar to synchronous code and can actually be very elegant.

Additionally, `$.ajax()` returns a promise and is well suited to be written as follows:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    return $.ajax();
}

ajaxFunction().then(function(response){
    // do whatever you want with the response
})
```

You simply can't write asynchronous code that way (`ajaxResult = ajaxFunction()`). The interpreter is going to keep trucking along line by line and ajaxResult will not be ready in time.

Read up on chaining $.Deferred's. It will really clean up your async code.